# Angular ngRX testing has been not separate correctly

Tags: angular, testing, ngrx

I got two files with separated tests in Angular 17 application. I'm using Karma and Jasmine and ngRX. I got following problem:

person.effectTests.spec.ts

```
describe('Person effects checker', () => {
  let effects: PersonEffects;
  let actions: Observable<any>;
  let spy: any;
  let service: PersonService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientTestingModule,
        StoreModule.forRoot({
          person: combineReducers(Reducers),
        }),
        LabelsModule],
      providers: [
        PersonEffects,
        provideMockActions(() => actions),
        PersonService,
      ],
    });

    effects = TestBed.inject(PersonEffects);
    service = TestBed.inject(PersonService);
  });

  it('getPerson$ should emit GetPersons action', () => {
    // arrange
    spy = spyOn(service, 'getByPersonEmail').and.returnValue(of(TEST_PERSON));

    const action = new appActions.GetPersonCars(TEST_VALUE_A, TEST_VALUE_B);
    const completion = new appActions.GetPersonData(personId, personEmail);

    actions = hot('-a', { a: action });
    const expected = cold('-b', { b: completion });

    // act and assert
    effects.getPerson$.subscribe( a => {
      expect(a).toEqual(completion);
    });

    expect(effects.get$).toBeObservable(expected);
  });
});
```

person.reducerTests.spec.ts

```
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [],
    imports: [StoreModule.forRoot(appReducers.reducers), StoreModule.forFeature('person', fromRoot.Reducers)]
  })
    .compileComponents();
})); 

it('Should return list of persons', inject([Store], (store: Store<fromRoot.State>) => {

  // arrange
  const expectedPersons: IPerson[] = TEST_PERSON_LIST;

  // act
  store.dispatch(new appActions.GetPersonData(personId, personEmail));

  // assert
  store.select(fromRoot.getPersons)
    .subscribe((data: State) => {
      expect(data.person).toEqual(expectedItems);
    });
}));
```

**When I run this tests separately both pass, but when I run them together  , effect test failed. In tested effect there is an error**

```
"Cannot assign to read only property "personCountry" of object [Object] [Object], type: "My_Application_Error"
```

effect code

```
get$: Observable<Action> = createEffect(() => this.action$.pipe(
  ofType(appActions.GetPersonData),
  mergeMap( (action: fromActions.GetPersonInfo) =>
    this.service.getByPersonEmail(action.PersonMail).pipe(
      map((data: IPerson[])  => {
        data = this.appService.translatePersonCountryName(data, action.entityName);
        return new appActions.GetPersonData(personId, personEmail);
      }),
      catchError(error => of( new fromErrors.MyAppError(error))),)
  )));

  translatePersonCountryName(persons: IPerson[], countryCode: string): IPerson[] {
    persons.forEach((p) => p.fieldName = this.getTranslation(countryCode, p.fieldName));
    return persons;
}
```

Why this tests are effected on each other? When I will comment this line in reducerTest file  there is no problem in effectTests...

```
store.dispatch(new appActions.GetPersonData(personId, personEmail));
```

Where can be a problem? Looks like there is a problem with translatePersonCountryName function, but why it pass when I run it separately?